# Why doesn't id-tool show latest added group?

Tags: users

I wanted to add myself to a group called vboxusers while the following situation occured:

At first let's see how it looks before we do anything:

```
$ id
uid=1001(me) gid=1001(me) groups=1001(me),4(adm),27(sudo),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
$ cat /etc/group | grep me
adm:x:4:me
sudo:x:27:me
lpadmin:x:109:me
me:x:1001:
```

Then I added myself to the group and checked again:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG vboxusers me
$ id
uid=1001(me) gid=1001(me) groups=1001(me),4(adm),27(sudo),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
$ cat /etc/group | grep me
adm:x:4:me
sudo:x:27:me
lpadmin:x:109:me
me:x:1001:
vboxusers:x:126:me
```

`id` still doesn't list me as being part of the group, while I definitely wrote the correct stuff into `/etc/groups`. What happened and what can I do that `id` also recognises it?

(just starting a new shell didn't change anything)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id` shows information about the process that invokes it (or more precisely, it shows information about itself, which it inherits from the process that invokes it). The group database is only consulted at login time, and it only affects processes descended from that login session. The login process is granted the groups listed in the group database, and all other processes inherit from their parent.

Starting a new shell doesn't make a difference, you need to log out and back in. You can test your changes by logging in in another console or with `ssh localhost` or with `su me`.

You can query the group database with `getent group vboxusers`. Unless your machine uses NIS or LDAP to obtain user and group information from a network server, this will give the same information as `grep '^vboxusers:' /etc/group`. Again, this information tells you what happens at login time, it is not consulted afterwards.

Comment: So presumably I have to logout + login to use any alterations to groups.

Comment: @pbhj Yes. Either log out of your session, or do `su - pbhj` or `ssh localhost` or the like if you want to run a command as the new group quickly but less conveniently.